# Вывод картинки в SurfaceView

Tags: glsurfaceview, android

Вывести изображение с камера в SurfaceView получается. А как вывести в SurfaceView картинку, если изображение с камеры отсутствует (камера выключена).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вышел из положение следующим образом:

```
private SurfaceView SV;
private SurfaceHolder holderSV;
private Camera camera;
```

Как создать SurfaceView и  как вывести на него изображение с камеры писать не буду. А вот вывод картинки вместо камеры делаю так:

```
if (buffer[1] == 4) {                       // если нужно вывести картинку cat
    SV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cat);
}
else {                                      // если нужно вывести изображение с камеры
    SV.setBackground(null);
    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holderSV);
    camera.startPreview();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно переопределить метод onDraw(Canvas canvas) у SurfaceView:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mbitmap, 0,0,null);

}
```

Где `mbitmap` - `Bitmap`, который нужно нарисовать.
Также у вашего `SurfaceView` нужно вызвать метод `setWillNotDraw(false);`, который укажет ему, что его нужно рисовать (вызывать `onDraw`). Без этого `onDraw` не будет вызван.  
Как определить, что камера не работает - думаю, задача тривиальная...

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то mbitmap нужно еще как то нарисовать. А мне необходимо вывести уже готовую картинку

Comment: @selya - в mbitmap надо загрузить как раз ту картинку, которую надо нарисовать. Нарисуется она этой строчкой:    

    canvas.drawBitmap(mbitmap, 0,0,null);

Comment: @metalurgus может, я не совсем корректно выразился, картинка представляет собой файл с расширением png, jpg и т.д. Если Вы и имели в виду файл, то тогда напишите, как его можно загрузить в mbitmap, а то я не нашел.

Comment: @selya
вы совершенно не умеете пользоваться поиском. Ответ на вопрос, как загрузить изображение в Bitmap, давался, наверное, уже как минимум 100 000 раз.      
Из ресурсов приложения:
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20load%20resource%20into%20bitmap      
из файла:  
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android+load+bitmap+from+file

Сразу первый ответ и там, и там правильный.